# How to get sum from array using javascript?

Tags: javascript, ejs

```
var data =[
    {
        name:"xyz",
        meals:[
         {num:3.5},{num:4 },{num:6.5},{num:3}
            ],
        deposits:[
            {date:"", amount:3000},
            {date:"", amount:2400},
            {date:"", amount:300},
        ];
    },
    {
        name:"abc",
        meals:[
         {num:3.5},{num:4 },{num:6.5},{num:3}
            ],
        deposits:[
            {date:"", amount:3000},
            {date:"", amount:2400},
            {date:"", amount:300},
        ];
    }
];
```

I want to get the sum of meals & deposits for every name or object.

Comment: Sorry, for any kind of error because i am a newbie

Comment: Please post actual data instead of images

Comment: @PrantaSaha what is expected output?

Comment: just use properly reduce function, after reading the documentation

Comment: @amrender singh,  I want to get total number of meals and amount of deposits for each person.

Comment: yow want to be included in object?or make different array for meals and deposits  which contains object?

Comment: @amrender,  no actually I am getting these data from my backend and i am showing these in a table where Row for each and there col (name, meals, amounts )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
var data =[{name:"xyz",meals:[{num:3.5},{num:4 },{num:6.5},{num:3}],deposits:[{date:"", amount:3000},{date:"", amount:2400},{date:"", amount:300}]},{name:"abc",meals:[{num:3.5},{num:4 },{num:6.5},{num:3}],deposits:[{date:"", amount:3000},{date:"", amount:2400},{date:"", amount:300}]}];
    
let result = data.map(({name, meals, deposits}) => ({name, meals : meals.reduce((a,c) => a + c.num, 0), deposits : deposits.reduce((a,c) => a + c.amount, 0)}));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: @PrantaSaha - Glad to help you :)